# Change length/distance of line from user input(canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Hope you're all good.

I'm working on floorplan built using canvas, my walls are connected by lines and I'm able to compute line length/distance from two points. Now what I want to achieve is a dynamic wall length from user input.

Here's a sample code.

```
    var wallPoints = [{
            "label" : 'A',
            "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
            "x2": 19.113499999999952, "y2": 132.33399999999997
        }, {
            "label" : 'B',
            "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": 132.33399999999997,
            "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": 132.33399999999997
        }, {
            "label" : 'C',
            "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
            "x2": 283.2734999999998, "y2": -76.96199999999996
        }, {
            "label" : 'D',
            "x1": 283.2734999999998, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
            "x2": 283.2734999999998, "y2": -25.146000000000015
        }, {
            "label" : 'E',
            "x1": 283.2734999999998, "y1": -25.146000000000015,
            "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": -25.146000000000015
        }, {
            "label" : 'F',
            "x1": 335.08950000000004, "y1": -25.146000000000015,
            "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": 132.33399999999997
    }];

    function setWallLength(index, wallLength) {
        // wallLength is from a user input e.g 100,200,300 etc
        var wall = wallPoints[index];

        // how to calculate length and update points here?
        // compute wall length
        // update wall length
        // walls should be relative to each other.
    }
```

I've added a code snippet so you can check it out. Also wall changes length should be relative to other walls so floorplan stays intact.

Hope someone could shed a light no this one.

Thanks a lot.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('lineDistance');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var wallPoints = [{
    "label" : 'A',
    "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
    "x2": 19.113499999999952, "y2": 132.33399999999997
   }, {
    "label" : 'B',
    "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": 132.33399999999997,
    "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": 132.33399999999997
   }, {
    "label" : 'C',
    "x1": 19.113499999999952, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
    "x2": 283.2734999999998, "y2": -76.96199999999996
   }, {
    "label" : 'D',
    "x1": 283.2734999999998, "y1": -76.96199999999996,
    "x2": 283.2734999999998, "y2": -25.146000000000015
   }, {
    "label" : 'E',
    "x1": 283.2734999999998, "y1": -25.146000000000015,
    "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": -25.146000000000015
   }, {
    "label" : 'F',
    "x1": 335.08950000000004, "y1": -25.146000000000015,
    "x2": 335.08950000000004, "y2": 132.33399999999997
  }]


  draw();

  function getWallLength(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
   return Math.sqrt(
     Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) +
     Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
  }

  function setWallLength(index, wallLength) {
   var wall = wallPoints[index];
   
   // how to calculate length and update points here?
   // compute wall length
   // update wall length
   // walls should be relative to each other.
      
      // redraw for changes
      draw();
  }

  function draw() {
   var centerX = canvas.width/3;
   var centerY = canvas.height/4;

      var controls = document.getElementById('controls');
      controls.innerHTML = '';

   for (var i in wallPoints) {
    var wall = wallPoints[i];

    context.save();
       context.translate(centerX,centerY);

    //create input
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    input.setAttribute('id', i);

    var wall_length = getWallLength(wall.x1,wall.y1,wall.x2,wall.y2);
    input.setAttribute('value', wall_length);

    // set event for wall length changes
    input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
     setWallLength(event.target.id, event.target.value);
    });

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = wall.label + ':';
    label.appendChild(input);
    controls.appendChild(label);

    // draw walls
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(wall.x1, wall.y1);
    context.lineTo(wall.x2, wall.y2);
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
        
        // draw wall labels
    context.font = 12 + "px arial";
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.fillStyle = context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";

    var dx = wall.x2-wall.x1;
    var dy = wall.y2-wall.y1;
    var midX = wall.x1 + dx*0.50;
    var midY = wall.y1 + dy*0.50;

    context.fillText(wall.label, midX, midY);

    context.restore();
   }
   
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div id="controls" class="wall-lengths">
 </div>
 <canvas id="lineDistance" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to right way to generate canvas.someminormistake may hapenp

Comment: @LDS, what do you mean?